# adminhtml - js works in edit.phtml but fails when moved to local.xml

Tags: ce-1.9.0.1, local.xml, prototype-js

I've added a small bit of prototype js to app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product/edit.phtml

```
$$("#status").invoke(
    'on', 
     'change',
     function(){
        Form.Element.setValue("status_updated",new Date);
    }
);
```

When I attempt to load it as an external file the script doesn't work anymore, no 404, no script error.

I've added the following to app/design/adminhtml/default/default/layout/local.xml

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addJs"><script>js/timestamp_update.js</script></action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_catalog_product_edit>
</layout>
```

If anyone has an idea it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your js is loaded before DOM, you need to do it like this:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
    $$("#status").invoke(
        'on',
        'change',
        function(){
            Form.Element.setValue("status_updated",new Date);
        }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Cleaning up the PrototypeJS code

```
$$("#status").invoke(
     'on', 
     'change',
     function(){
        Form.Element.setValue("status_updated",new Date);
     }
);
```

can be optimized to

```
$('status').observe('change',function(){
    $('status_updated').setValue(new Date());
});
```

`on()` and `observe()` can be used interchangeably unless you are observing delegated events, then you need to use `on()`